# Dynamic Regression Prediction with Flask(or sth. similar)

Tags: machine-learning

as a self learner Data Scientist I am working on deploying my model in order to get regular predictions. And I need your guidance about deployment section, in which I know nothing about and there is nobody around to guide me. There is not any line of code etc, so I am just asking for your theoretical opinions.

My process will go on like this:

1- Every 2 hours, system will run a query and save a csv file to a specific location. It will overwrite of course. And this task is on me, **I am not asking about it**. This csv file is the prediction dataset actually, which will be retrieved by ML model periodically to make predictions on it.

2- I have to make predictions, lets say, every 2 hour. My service should retrieve this csv file automatically from the local path I will define.

3- Then it should make predictions based on the model I will define for it in pickle form.

4- Finally it should download the results or final dataframe in csv format again into the same path as predictions.csv for example. It should overwrite of course.

For this process, I am making my research on Flask Web Services. **But I must ask you, is this process possible with flask applications?** As you can see, there is not any manual trigger in this process, everything is automatic, no one needs to visit a web page or hit a run button etc. If you can suggest me any resources or web pages that you think may be beneficial for me, it is highly welcome.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

This seems more like an ETL job than an API one. Of course you can have both, but in your specific case I would design it as a series of **tasks** where each task you extract, transform and load data.

Airflow is an amazing tool for that: https://github.com/apache/airflow
In airflow, each ETL is defined as a DAG (directed acyclic graph) with a series of tasks that are customized by you.

So, for your specific case, you would create a DAG with following tasks:

- Retrieve data, prep if necessary.
- Make predictions
- Save new dataset predictions.csv.

You can schedule it like a cron job to run at each 2 hours. I highly recommend you to look at.

Comment: Also, feel free to contact me if you have any further questions and need help. I am starting to learn this kind of stuff and I think I can help you out at this beginning.